# Recover Outlook Express Accounts from hard drive

Tags: outlook-express

I am working on a friend's computer that crashed. I backed up all of their files and reinstalled Windows XP. I am now working on setting up recovering their email.

I have recovered all of the email from the Identities folder. I just need to recover the mail account(s). I ran across [How to back up and to restore Outlook Express data](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/270670), but this doesn't tell you how to restore from files; you have to export the account from Outlook Express, which wasn't an option since the computer crashed.

Are there any tools or methods to do this?

## EDIT

I am also concerned about the address book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the adress book is not part of Outlook Express, Windows Address Book is a separate program and the data are rather easy to recover: search the drive for `*.wab` files.

unfortunately, the mail accounts settings (and messages rules) for Outlook Express are stored in the Windows registry and not in a file that can be easily restored. location:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Account Manager
```